# What is $r_u{_v}$ in the kNN algorithm for collaborative filtering?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, recommender-system

In equation (1) from [Toscher, Jahrer, and Legenstein's Improved Neighborhood-Based Algorithms for Large-Scale Recommender Systems (2008)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.504.7198&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

> $\hat{r}_u{_i} = \frac{\Sigma_j{_∈}{_N}{_{_k}}{_(}{_u}{_,}{_i}{_)}
> > c_i{_j} r_u{_v}}
> >        {\Sigma_j{_∈}{_N}{_{_k}}{_(}{_u}{_,}{_i}{_)} c_i{_j}}$
>
> where $N_k{_(}{_u}{_,}{_i}{_)}$ denotes the set of the k items most
>   similar to item i that were rated by user u.

what is $r_u{_v}$? The user rating for item v, but what is v?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of the indicies of $r$ is spelled out on the first page of the paper

> We define the set of users as the set of integers {1, . . . , m}
>   and the set of items as the set of integers {1, . . . , n}. The
>   $m \times n$ rating matrix $R = [r_{ui}] \ 1 \leq u \leq m;1 \leq i \leq n$ stores the rating sof users for items where $r_{ui}$ is the rating of user u for item i.

So $v$ is one of the items in the suite of objects you are attempting to recommend.  Or, more pedantically, the *index* of one of the items after you have assigned unique indices to every item in your suite.

In the equation (1), I believe the $v$ is a type left over from a copy and paste.  It should be a $j$, i.e. we are summing over all the similar items and weighting their rating by the similarity.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Which item is $v$ actually referring to?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Ok, I think that's a typo.

Comment: A possible reference for this is equation 8 in http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/papers/NbrRSsurvey2011.pdf

Comment: I believe you're correct--it seems to be a typo. Thanks for the reference @RoryT!